# PowerShell - psake run clean up script after all tasks?

Tags: powershell, psake

Is there a hook in psake to run a clean up block after ALL talks (not just per task)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is not such an option, as far as I know. There are a few related issues:

- [BeforeAll & AfterAll instructions](https://github.com/psake/psake/issues/181)
- [Cleanup / always run task](https://github.com/psake/psake/issues/170)

If this feature is important, you may take a look at the similar tool
[Invoke-Build](https://github.com/nightroman/Invoke-Build). It supports such
features as two functions defined in a build script: `Enter-Build` (invoked
before the first task, a place for initialization) and `Exit-Build` (invoked
when a build is finished or failed, i.e. always, a place for clean up).

Comment: by no means ideal, but overriding this alias works too 
Set-Alias CleanupEnvironment global:Invoke-CleanUpEnvironment -Scope global